# "@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title" sets the color to white instead of grey in android L

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

Android L uses white background for notifications and grey color for the text on it. But, `"@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title"` still sets the color of `TextView` to same white color like in KitKat or previous versions. It should return the grey color used in new notification style of Android L.
How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems android-L doesn't override `"@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title"`, instead introduces new style

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title">
    <item name="textColor">@color/primary_text_default_material_light</item>
    <item name="textSize">@dimen/notification_title_text_size</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

We could make use of both the API based values folders to handle this in proper way.

`/values/styles.xml`

```
<style
    name="NotificationTitle"
    parent="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title" />
```

`/values-21/styles.xml`

```
<style
    name="NotificationTitle"
    parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title" />
```

Now call the following line in your `TextView`

```
android:textAppearance="@style/NotificationTitle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me to resolve this error. In your `styles.xml`, add the following:

```
    <style name="TextAppearance">
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar">
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff6b6b6b</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Info">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff6b6b6b</item>
    </style>
```